# What is the "ism" where sex is considered for procreation only and what is the opposite where sex is consider for recreational purpose

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I am looking for single word or phrase in following context

1.) An "ism" (belief or school of thought) where sex (Activity or activities) is considered for procreation only

and
2.) an "ism" (belief or school of thought) where sex is considered for for recreational (pleasure) purpose only

Comment: Would you please explain your question a little more clearly, please?  Are you comparing a view (1) where the only morally acceptable reason that justifies sex is procreation and a contrary view (2) that the only morally acceptable reason that justifies sex is pleasure?   Or is it that view (1) is being contrasted with a view (3) procreation is morally irrelevant to sex and pleasure is a morally sufficient reason for sex?

Comment: You need to clarify that you want a pair of words, not "a single word."

Comment: @Tuffy yes it is comparison between 2 opposing view let along "having no sex" view. In the first view i am talking about people who hold a view (morality or not) that sex is an activity 99.9% for procreation (its recreational value is discarded) and in second about people who hold view that sex is activity for recreational purpose which may or may not include procreation.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin I dont want to stick to single word or pair of words, it matter that it elicit a response matching my requirement

Comment: There is something a bit muddled going on here.  As soon as you mention an 'ism' ideology (or ethics) rather than psychology comes in.  Evolution designed humans, like other creatures, to reproduce.  If not, the species would become extinct.  Various hormones  are at work 'incentivising' sexual reproduction.  Individual attitudes to sexual activity differ and may differ at different stages in life.  Nowadays there are relatively few people who, after the wanted 2 kids, decide on celibacy.  Some may prefer AID to copulation.  But why do you need special words?

Answer (score 4):

The latter point of view is often called **sex positivity** by its supporters. [The American Psychological Association gives this definition:](https://dictionary.apa.org/sex-positivity)

> a positive attitude or stance toward sexual activity between consenting individuals when this is seen as promoting healthy relationships and forms of self-expression. Sex is seen as neither good nor bad, per se, and the purpose of sexual relations is not deemed to be confined exclusively to procreation through marital coitus

Supporters of "sex positivity" generally characterize their opponents as having an attitude of **sex negativity,** [defined by The American Psychological Association as:](https://dictionary.apa.org/sex-negativity)

> a negative attitude or stance toward any sexual behavior other than procreative marital coitus

This terminology is, of course, rather biased, but you're going to have trouble finding unbiased terminology in this area.

Answer (score 2):

2: "Enjoyment" could be *hedonism*:

> living and behaving in ways that mean you get as much pleasure out of life as possible, according to the belief that the most important thing in life is to enjoy yourself [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hedonism)]
>
> The doctrine or theory of ethics in which pleasure is regarded as the chief good, or the proper end of action. [[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85405)] [probably paywalled]

These definitions don't mention sex specifically, but sex-for-pleasure is definitely hedonistic.

A word for (1) is more difficult; even the Catholic Church, which views sex without allowing the possibility of procreation as sinful, doesn't mandate procreation as the **only** end. It can be enjoyable too.

Comment: It can be hard to find a word for a belief nobody has ever seriously espoused. Even the belief that people (at least some people) should never have sex at all is more common than that it should only be for procreation.